# Django (mezzanine) urls catching everything

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm writing some custom views in the admin of a django project, should be simple. I have an "events" page and i want to create a "event" page (exactly the same as the django polls tutorial but in the admin, the event page would be the same as the detail view.)
No i cannot use the built in functionality as normal using foreignkeys etc and need to build from scratch.

urls.py:

```
admin.autodiscover()
def get_admin_urls(urls):
    def get_urls():
        my_urls =  [
           url(r'^my_cms/events', views.events, name="events"),
           url(r'^my_cms/events/(?P<event_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
    return get_urls
admin_urls = get_admin_urls(admin.site.get_urls())
admin.site.get_urls = admin_urls

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns("",
    ("^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

So.. 
visiting  .../admin/my_cms/events/ works
but       .../admin/my_cms/events/xxxxxx  just displays the same events page, rather than the detail view

if i change the url pattern to anything other than "events" eg:

```
url(r'^my_cms/events', views.events, name="events"),
url(r'^my_cms/[anything]/(?P<event_id>[0-9]+)/$',
```

then it will display the event view correctly...

So my question is why is the first url catching everything? i can put anything (.../admin/my_cms/events/anythingilike) and it will display the events page?

Joe

Comment: Instead of `url(r'^my_cms/events', views.events, name="events")` try `url(r'^my_cms/events/$', views.events, name="events")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `r'^my_cms/events'` doesn't have a `$` at the end. That means, only the beginning of this URL is checked, not the ending.

To illustrate, `r'^my_cms/events'` will match any URL that begins with `'my_cms/events'`, example:

```
'my_cms/events'
'my_cms/events/xxxxxx'
'my_cms/eventsxxxxxx'
```

So, even if you make a request to the detail view at `'my_cms/events/xxxxxx'`, the events page URL is matched. Once Django finds a match, it doesn't check further URLs and calls the related view.

To fix, add a `$` sign at end of your URL regexp, like this:

```
url(r'^my_cms/events/$', views.events, name="events"),
```

Comment: Thanks, annoyingly simple..:)